# What are the guidelines for set Djava.library.path variable in Java

Tags: java, windows, path, environment-variables

In general to path variable and in specific to setting Djava.library.path variable, is there a strict guideline in defining the values to this?

If yes, are there any consequences. I certainly do not have much experience with this. Hence, if you can provide me some examples, scenarios under which this might results in an error/undesired behaviour. That would be suffice my question.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Setting java.library.path and LD_LIBRARY_PATH are not exactly the same. There is a subtle difference between them which can cause undesired behaviour in some situations. For better explanation look at http://kalpakrg.wordpress.com/2009/01/09/java-library-path-and-ld_library_path/

Comment: Alright! But, either ways. What would be the guidelines. specifically on spaces and non-alphanumeric characters?